# Not primary key Guid autogeneration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this table:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

`Id` is the auto-generated PK and I want `Guid` to also be auto-generated.

```
builder.Property(x => x.Identifier).HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())");
```

This configuration did not worked(Due to fact that Identifier is not nullable I could not omit it) but if I make it nullable after insert Identifier is NULL

How to create an auto-generated identifier?

Comment: Does `.HasDefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid())` work?

Comment: @TimothyG. No. Also tried .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); same issue "Cannot insert null" if i make guid nullable then nothing is generated and the column is null

Answer (score 0):

did it like this

```
builder.Property(x => x.OrderIdentifier).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
```

not shure if it is correct, but it works for me